# Как при наведении на элемент отобразить div? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, hover

Есть несколько однотипных элементов с одним классом - "item"

```
<a href="#1">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/u1.png" alt="img1">
    <p>Детские<br> походы</p>
    <div class="order"><span>Заказать</span></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы "order"(display:none) выскакивал только в том итеме на который навели. Как это реализовать?

в принципе, этот код работает, 
`.order { display: none; } .item:hover .order { display: block; }`
но так как это ссылка, то при наведении на сам "order" (кружок "заказать") пропадает
`opacity: 0.5`
 у итема(рисунок справа). Как сделать чтобы прозрачность не пропадала? Пробовал добавить
 `.order:hover .item { opacity: 0.5; }`
 но почему-то не работает, да и если сработает, то будет мигать при наведении(так как ховер то на одном элементе, то на другом)

Comment: Уточните, что значит "на том итеме"? Внутри итема, на который навели, или спозиционировать рядом с итемом?

Comment: внутри.............

Comment: В вашем случае возможно лучше даже будет использовать не один блок `.order` для всех, а для каждого итема свой, или вам важно, чтобы был именно один `.order`?

Comment: Можно и для каждого сделать, не суть

Comment: Как это тогда в джаваскрипт реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если разместить блок `.order` внутрь каждого `.item` вот так:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="img/u1.png" alt="img1">
    <p>Детские<br> походы</p>
    <div class="order"><span>Заказать</span></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="img/u2.png" alt="img2">
    <p>Детские<br> походы</p>
    <div class="order"><span>Заказать</span></div>
</div>
```

То на jQuery можно реализовать следующим образом:

```
$('.item')
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).find('.order').show();
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).find('.order').hide();
    });
```

Также можно реализовать без JavaScript на CSS:

```
.order { display: none; }
.item:hover .order { display: block; }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в принципе, этот код работает,

`.order { display: none; }
.item:hover .order { display: block; }`

но так как это ссылка(я подправил пост+изображение), то при наведении на сам "order" (кружок "заказать") пропадает 'opacity: 0.5' у итема(рисунок справа). Как сделать чтобы прозрачность не пропадала? 

Пробовал добавить
' .order:hover .item { opacity: 0.5; } '
но почему-то не работает, да и если сработает, наверное, будет мигать при наведении(так как ховер то на одном элементе, то на другом)

Answer (score 2):

решил таким способом

```
<div class="item">
<img src="img/u1.png" alt="img1">
<p>Детские<br> походы</p>
<div class="order"><span>Заказать</span></div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.item')
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).find('.order').show().parent().addClass("opacity");
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).find('.order').hide().parent().removeClass("opacity");
});
```

css

`.opacity{
    opacity: 0.6;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #555;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.order{
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    z-index: 99;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
    background: #c00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: opacity .3s;   
}
.item:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s;   
}
.item:hover:before,
.item:hover .order{
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/000000" alt="img1">
    <p>Детские<br> походы</p>
    <div class="order"><span>Заказать</span></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/000000" alt="img2">
    <p>Детские<br> походы</p>
    <div class="order"><span>Заказать</span></div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #555;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.order{
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    z-index: 99;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
    background: #c00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.item:hover .order{
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/000000" alt="img1">
    <p>Детские<br> походы</p>
    <div class="order"><span>Заказать</span></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/000000" alt="img2">
    <p>Детские<br> походы</p>
    <div class="order"><span>Заказать</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var  item = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
console.log(item);
for(let i = 0; i < item.length;i++){
    item[i].addEventListener('mouseenter',(e)=>{
        let child = item[i].getElementsByClassName('order')[0];
        child.style.display = 'block';
    })
    item[i].addEventListener('mouseleave',()=>{
        let child = item[i].getElementsByClassName('order')[0];
        child.style.display = 'none';
    })
}
```

Также обычный CSS

```
.item:hover .order{
    display: block;
}
```